# Unusual word order in "Fear not this night"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, word-order

Yesterday, I've listened to a song called "Fear not this night".
I find the syntax unusual (as a foreigner, I have never encountered it). Is it the same meaning as "Don't fear this night" ? What's the slight difference between these 2 ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an archaic structure, and can be seen in the Bible verse [Isaiah 41:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2041:10&version=NKJV) in the King James Version.

> Fear not, for I am with you;
>   Be not dismayed, for I am your God.
>   I will strengthen you,
>   Yes, I will help you,
>   I will uphold you with My righteous right hand

The [New International Version](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isa.41.10) reads:

> So do not fear, for I am with you;
>       do not be dismayed, for I am your God.
>   I will strengthen you and help you;
>       I will uphold you with my righteous right hand.

"Fear not" has the same meaning as "Do not fear". The song-writer probably used more poetic language to express their meaning - see also "[artisitic license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license)".

Comment: Thank you, would it be weird to use this construction verbally in an everyday usage ?

Comment: Yes, it would not be common for people to use the construction "[Verb] not" instead of "Do not [verb]".

Comment: It is the usual construction in Shakespeare, but nowadays used only in poetry or for rhetorical effect.